# Getting an access token for Azure Key Vault in Rider using Azure CLI

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I am currently trying to get keyvault integration in our project.
I am running Ubuntu (FF) and working in Rider.

Things i have done in order to achieve this is:

- Create an access policy for my AD user for the keyvault
- Installed azure cli, running `az login`, `az account set subscription`
- Installed Azure Toolkit for Rider (not sure if this was necessary)

I have also verified that I can get an access token through the azure cli by running `az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net`

When I run my app, I get this error:

```
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/d8ed8deb-97d7-4062-a791-c45b9561ec8e. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/d8ed8deb-97d7-4062-a791-c45b9561ec8e. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) endpoint. Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI setup.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/d8ed8deb-97d7-4062-a791-c45b9561ec8e. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/d8ed8deb-97d7-4062-a791-c45b9561ec8e. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired.
```

I've tried different options for the connection string, but it whatever I try it says it cannot obtain an access token. Since I've logged in with `az login` I think obtaining access to the vault should just work, but I am probably missing something.

EDIT: added code

I am following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication

```
        var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var client = new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(config.Url, client, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

As you can see I am trying to add the secrets that are in the keyvault to a configuration.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme

Comment: You state that it works fine using Azure CLI - in what way are your trying to obtain an access token in your "app"?

Comment: @MMThornberg after logging in using `azure login` with the azure cli, the application should be able to use my environment to be able to authenticate. (I think there might be a service running or an agent that accomplishes this). I am not entirely sure how it works exactly, and I think that this is where I may have missed a step. However I am following every step that is provided as far as I can tell. @krishg I have done everything that is listed in the article you provided but the problem persist.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @JoyWang I added the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access azure keyvault, e.g. secret locally via Azure CLI auth, you could use [`AzureCliCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-dotnet) to auth.

Use the code below after login Azure CLI via `az login`.

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://myvault.azure.vaults.net/"), new AzureCliCredential());
//something you want e.g. get secret
secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
```

If you want to access the key in the keyvault, you could use

```
var client = new KeyClient(new Uri("https://myvault.azure.vaults.net/"), new AzureCliCredential());
key = client.GetKey("key-name");
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/key-vault

**Update:**

If you want to use the `AzureServiceTokenProvider` via the  Azure CLI auth, please add [`RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) in your code.

After login Azure CLI, run the code :

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli);
var client = new KeyVaultClient(
        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
```

Comment: I will try if I can achieve the same objective with this, but I think in my case the route Im following makes more sense... the one that doesnt work yet I mean :-)

Comment: @Glubus Your are using the old sdk, I recommend you to use the new sdk, if you still want to use the old one, try the update in my reply. And seems I don't see you get the secret, may be you need to use something like `var secrets = client.GetSecretsAsync(keyVaultPath).Result;` if you want to get the secret?

Comment: Hey, the update in your reply did not work for me unfortunately, but I suspect that the solution does lie somewhere in that direction. To be honest I think using your method will be fine for me. I just need to try it out, which I will. I will report back to you if I get what I am trying to do.